# How does UITableView's section index change the cells' contentView margins?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a `UITableView` with a section index. My issue is that the section index adds a 15 pt right margin on all the cells, despite the fact that I've set `cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero`, `cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero`, and `cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO`.

Inspecting the frame of the cells' content views over time, they appear to be covering the full table view horizontally in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, but are at some point changed to be 15 pts narrower (320 -> 305).

I would like to counteract this behavior (i.e., make the section index render on top of the cells' content views). Is there any official way to prevent the cells from shrinking due to a section index being present?

Comment: Did `[cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero]` work in `[tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:]`?

Comment: @ozgur Ah yes, I'm doing that too, forgot to mention it. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section index does not change the layout of tableView or cell, by default it lays over the tableView. You just have to clear the default background color on section index using these 2 lines:

```
tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

by using above lines, you will see your tableView section index as shown in screenshot:

[image]

Hope it helps!